# Tensor double dot product

Tags: matlab, tensor-products

I have two tensors that i must calculate double dot product.
matrix A is rank 2 
and matrix B is rank 4.
I want to multiply them with Matlab and I know in Matlab it becomes:
A : B = trace (A*B)
but it has one error and it says: **Inner matrix dimensions must agree**
So how can I solve this problem?
anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: What size are A and B?

Comment: A is 3*3 and B is 6*6

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only calculate this explictly if you have dyadic- and polyadic-product forms of your two tensors, i.e., A = a b and B = c d e f, where a, b, c, d, e, f are vectors. Beware that there are two definitions for double dot product, even for matrices both of rank 2: (a b) : (c d) = (a.c) (b.d) or (a.d) (b.c), where "." is the usual single-dot scalar product for vectors. One possible answer would thus be (a.c) (b.d) (e f); another would be (a.d) (b.c) (e f), i.e., a matrix of rank 2 in any case. Of course A:B $\not =$ B:A in general, if A and B do not have same rank, so be careful in which order you wish to double-dot them as well.